# Which is more advisable to use in NodeJs, Passport or JWT and why?

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, express-jwt

I am new to Node Js and Currently working on a project with Express Js. I discover that User and can be achieved either through the Passport library or JSONWebTokens(JWT). So i was wondering which is the better option and why?

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use them together. However, in short, passport is a module with many 'strategies' to help you authenticate users with multiple platforms. Passport-JWT is a strategy you could use as the auth strategy. This makes it easy when you use multiple ways to authenticate with your application. E.g. google, facebook, jwt, etc.